# Magento 1.7 Theme issue

Tags: magento

Trying to change a theme in magento 1.7. Editing the page.xml file but the effects are not being seen. Changes the  tags in page.xml but none of the changes appear on site.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All layout files will be cached (unless you have this disabled) - try and clear your layout cache first.  Do this by logging into the admin area and go to system > cache management and refreshing the Layout cache type (second option down on a standard install).

If you are still in development, it may be an idea to turn caching off.

If the updates that you have made still do not take effect, then double check you are editing the correct file by making sure you are working in the correct package and theme.

Just as an aside, also look into using the local.xml file for all of your core layout overrides instead of copying over the core file into your theme and editing.  It makes for a better/faster workflow and and cleaner less error prone upgrade path (though there are scenarios where it isn't the best option)

Answer (score 1):

- Clear your cache (the page layout updates XML tree is a cache item)
- Make sure you are editing the correct page.xml file (try making the changes in local.xml in the same layout directory to make sure that you are in the correct theme)